# How to make Section headers to be columns in ssis

Tags: ssis, transform

I have a file that I need to transform using SSIS and in looks like this:

```
Date : 20 SEP 2011

Renewal Business Bordereau for August 2011 - AXC Ins Co - Facultative

PolicyNo, LastName, FirstName, SX, Date Of Birth, Policy Type
========,=========,==========,===,==============,============
0001211 , Oscar    , David    , M , 29011977     , DEATH
0001213 , Obeten   , Samul    , F , 29031978     , DISABILITY
0001214 , Owen     , David    , M , 29031975     , DEATH

Date : 20 SEP 2011
   Lapsed Business Bordereau for August 2011 - AXC Ins Co - Facultative
PolicyNo, LastName, FirstName, SX, Date Of Birth, Policy Type
========,=========,==========,===,==============,============
0001424 , Darren  , Jacoobs  , F , 29031996     , DISABILITY
0001635 , Owen    , Bergdal  , F , 29031965     , DISABILITY
0001132 , Ahmed   , Muhamad  , M , 29031977     , DEATH


Date : 20 SEP 2011
   New Business Bordereau for August 2011 -  AXC Ins Co - Facultative

PolicyNo, LastName, FirstName, SX, Date Of Birth, Policy Type
========,=========,==========,===,==============,============
0001210 , Djibril , Pogba    , M , 29031977     , LIFE
0001999 , Thabang , Ngwenya  , M , 29031966     , DEATH
```

I want it to look like the one below   in which the movementType and Date columns are created and filled with the data in the section headers like the following

```
PolicyNo, LastName, FirstName, SX, Date Of Birth , Policy Type , MovementType     , Date
0001211 , Oscar    , David    , M , 29011977     , DEATH       , Renewal Business , August 2011
0001213 , Obeten   , Samul    , F , 29031978     , DISABILITY  , Renewal Business , August 2011
0001214 , Owen     , David    , M , 29031975     , DEATH       , Renewal Business , August 2011
0001424 , Darren   , Jacoobs  , F , 29031996     , DISABILITY  , Lapsed Business  , August 2011
0001635 , Owen     , Bergdal  , F , 29031965     , DISABILITY  , Lapsed Business  , August 2011
0001132 , Ahmed    , Muhamad  , M , 29031977     , DEATH       , Lapsed Business  , August 2011
0001210 , Djibril  , Pogba    , M , 29031977     , LIFE        , New Business     , August 2011 
0001999 , Thabang  , Ngwenya  , M , 29031966     , DEATH       , New Business     , August 2011
```

Note: This is not a combination of more that one file it is a file with different section headers, each header containing the MovementType and the date (movementtype refers to the transaction type and date refers to the transaction date) of which when you look at each header you will see its August 2011. A person can only exist in one section and the policynumber can only be found in one section as only one transaction can take place

Comment: Your final column, Date, with values of August 2011: where does that come from? Do you need to parse this from file names? What is the business logic for combining data across these 3 sources? What if a person exists in 2/3 files? What if policy number 0001213 lists Samul and Samuel in different files, which one is more correct?

Comment: This is not a combination of more that one file it is a file with different section headers, each header containing the MovementType and the date  (movementtype refers to the transaction type and date refers to the transaction date) of which when you look at each header you will see its August 2011. A person can only exist in one section and the policynumber can only be found in one section as only one transaction can take place.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is with a script task.   Either one that does the entire import, or one that pre-modifies the text file so that it is in a standard format for a dataflow task.